# Tverberg's theorem in CAT(0) spaces

Tags: co.combinatorics, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, convexity, alexandrov-geometry

Does [Tverberg's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tverberg%27s_theorem) hold  for CAT(0) spaces of covering dimension $d<\infty$:

Is it true that for any $d$-dimensional $CAT(0)$-space $X$ and a subset $E\subset X$ of cardinality $(d + 1)(r - 1) + 1$, there exists a point $x\in X$ and a partition of $E$ into $r$ subsets $E_1,...,E_r$, such that $x$ belongs to the intersection of closed convex hulls of the subsets $E_i$?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. Let $X$ be a tripod (three segments with one common endpoint), $d=1$, $r=2$ and $E$ the set of the 3 leaf points.

Comment: But it is okey for 4 points...

Comment: It seems that $2^{n+1}$ points in $n$-dimensional CAT(0) space can be always divided in two groups.

Comment: So, this might parallel the situation with "topological Tverberg's theorem".

Comment: @Misha, I do not know what is "topological Tverberg's theorem"; is it for a contractible space with contractible sets instead of convex hull? any ref?

Comment: In a Hadamard $d$-manifold, $d+2$ points seems to be enough for $r=2$. This follows by applying Borsuk-Ulam theorem to a suitable barycentric map.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin: Anton: Topological Tverberg deals with continuous maps of simplices (with the given vertex sets) instead of convex hulls, but the question is the same. It is usually asked in the context of $R^d$. It is known for $r=p^m$, where $p$ are prime numbers, but is open in general. My question was motivated by the guess that in the CAT(0) case things should be easier than in the pure topological setting. The right question seems to be to restrict to Hadamard manifolds. As Sergey noticed (I feels really silly for not checking the 1-dimensional case) is that the answer in $CAT(0)$...

Comment: non-manifold case is different. However, it would be interesting to figure out what the right bound is in the pure CAT(0) case. At the moment, I do not have a conjecture. Here is the reference to topological Tverberg: http://www.renyi.hu/~barany/cikkek/5.pdf.

Comment: @Misha, what about Helly's theorem? It boils down to the following: if the $(d+1)$-simplex is mapped to a space of dimension $d$, then the images of $d$-faces have a common point. This looks like something standard, but my knowledge of this stuff is too limited.

Comment: Answering my previous comment: see Theorem 1.1 in arXiv:1011.1802 for $r=2$. (Thanks to Roman Karasev who informed me about this reference.)